# A $*$-closed algebra of compact operators is completely reducible

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, compact-operators

In page 13 of Lang's $SL_2$ there is a proof that for a $*$-closed algebra $\mathscr A$ of compact operators on a Hilbert space $H$, $H$ is completely reducible.

The proof follows by taking the orthogonal complement $F$ of a maximal orthogonal family of irreducible subspaces and finding a new irreducible subspace.

To find the new irreducible subspace, we cook up a hermitian operator $A$ from an arbitrary operator in the algebra.

$$A = \frac {\tilde{A}+\tilde{A}^*}{2} + i\frac{\tilde{A} - \tilde{A}^*}{2}$$

Then, as in the spectral theorem, we can find an eigenvector $v$ for $A$ in $F$ that generates an irreducible space for $A$.

My problem is seeing how this irreducible space, which Lang denotes by $\overline{Av}$, is irreducible for the entire algebra $\mathscr A$. By the way, why do we take the closure $\overline{Av}$?

Comment: $\overline{A v}$ doesn't make sense, $Av$ is just $\lambda v$, ie a point, its not even a vector space. Maybe you mean the closure *span* of $Av$, but this is a 1-d vector space and thus closed, and it certainly *doesn't* need to be invariant. I think what is meant is $\overline{\mathscr A v}$, which is invariant, but I believe it definitely *doesn't* need to be irreducible.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you that $\overline{Av}$ instead of $\overline{\mathscr A v}$ was probably a typing error, but you can actually find a $v$ for which it is irreducible. Take an invariant subspace $M\subset F$ such that $M_\lambda$ has minimal dimension and $v\in M$. Then $\overline{\mathscr A v}\subset M$ and if $\overline{\mathscr A v}$ were not irreducible, it would contradict minimality of $M_\lambda$